# How to start JAR in separate window from a .bat script?

Tags: java, windows, jar, batch-file

I need to start a jar file with a *.bat file so that as it executes the Java command, it detaches from the terminal window (command prompt) and does not block the rest of the script. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

java.exe will always display a terminal window, you need to use javaw.exe instead:

```
start javaw -jar myjarfile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start /B java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

Comment: window will remain open until main thread won't finish its execution

Comment: @Jigar: What is it not satisfying? Could you please edit the question to clarify what he is asking for?

Comment: @Jigar: Doesn't `/B` eliminate the window? According to the `start` command's help, `/B` "Start[s] application without creating a new window."

Comment: it mean it will not open new window but will invoke in the same window. OP wants no window